# FactoryGirl - How to generate hierarchy of category entries in database before running tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, factory-bot

I am building an ecommerce website, the core of which is a catalogue module - it contains about 20 categories each of which has between 5 & 30 subcategories, products are then associated with subcategories.

I am trying to figure out how to create a parent category & then at least 2 subcategories which are associated with the same parent using FactoryGirl.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Factory.define :parent_category do |f|
  f.name "MetalWork"
end

Factory.define :child_category do |f|
  f.name "Wedling"
  f.association :parent_category
  f.metatitle ""
  f.metadescription ""
end
```

I am thinking of using a sequence to generate the child category name & SEO data, however if I then generate 2 child_category models using:

```
FactoryGirl.build_list(:child_category, 2)
```

it will create two separate parent categories, which is not what I want.

Its important that there are at least two child categories because we need to ensure that various SEO data being saved with the child category models displays both on the correct pages.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I know this is probably a very newbie question, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a hash to any factory call to override any of the attributes - that goes for the `build_list` call too:

```
parent = Factory(:category, :name => "Test Category")
FactoryGirl.build_list(:child_category, 2, :parent_category => parent)
```

See the examples in the section "Building and creating multiple records" in the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something like

```
# spec/support/factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :parent_category do
    name 'MetalWork'
  end

  factory :child_category do
    name 'Wedling'
    metatitle ''
    metadescription ''
  end
end

# some_controller_spec.rb
before :each do
  @parent = Factory :parent_directory
  (5 + rand(26)).times do
    # replace :parent_id with whatever attribute
    # you have to store parent category
    @child = Factory :child_directory, :parent_id => @parent.id
    # next you can fabricate your products with :category => @child
    # ...
  end
end
```